# convenience way for rolling back of liquibase in spring boot microservice

Tags: spring, postgresql, maven, spring-boot, liquibase

We are using liquibase for databases used in our springboot microservices.

Our SRE team are forced to maintain several versions and go back and forward among different releases. Moreover, they do not have access to maven or liquibase cli in production environments.

We are looking for seamless rolling back and upgrading but no luck so far. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [liqubiase database tags](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/tag_database.html).

With them you'll be able to capture data model versions you need.

Then take a look at [liquibase rollback](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/rollback.html) to tag functionality.

With that you'll be able to roll back to certain stages of your data model.

Since your SRE team doesn't have access to maven or liqubiase, perhaps you'll be able to choose what liqbuiase changeSets to execute with your application properties or perhaps with liquibase [context](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/contexts.html),

**UPDATE**

You can also use rollback by `changeSetId` or `changeSetAuthor` e.g.:

```
<changeSet id="foo" author="bar">
    <rollback changeSetId="ID" changeSetAuthor="AUTHOR"/>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: Thanks but I quite don't get your last paragraph which is the most important one for me, how to execute rollback? in changeset DB table I have only changeset numbers and no useful data for them to run SQLs, in rollback scripts, I got SQL commands but it's kinda a mess for a PAAS service to require them to run SQL files each time the move back, considering all buriers in permissions and running scripts

Comment: Since I'm not familiar with the architecture of your application and environment it runs on, I can't suggest any clear way of doing this. From what I understand, you can use `changeSetId` and/or `changeSetAuthor` to rollback the changesets you need. I've updated my answer.

Comment: To rollback changeset I would need maven or CLI, isn't it? My changesets already having rollback but moving back and forth is not applying them automatically so I need a way for our team to execute it easily

Comment: Ideally - yes. But as I understand, since your SRE team has only access to application `jar` file, then the only option I see is to make changeSets run automatically during application deployment. So you'll have to figure out how to do so. My guess would be to group the changeSets by versions and use `application.properties` to somehow trigger the changeSets you need. It doesn't look very clean, but it may work. Perhaps, there're other ways which I'm not aware of :)